# Is mysqli_real_escape_string safe?

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-injection

I´m new in PHP and I´ve realised that my database connection, using a php form (with user and pass text inputs) was totally unsafe:

This was working, but was unsafe:

```
<?php
$link=mysqli_connect('localhost','xx','xx','xx');
$sql='  SELECT * FROM usuarios 
        WHERE username="'.$_POST['usuario'].'" 
        AND pass="'.$_POST['usuario'].'"
     ';
$rs=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

So, I´ve read about mysqli_real_escape_string, and decided to try it out:

```
<?php    
$link=mysqli_connect('localhost','xx','xx','xx');
$usuario=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["usuario"]);
$clave=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["clave"]);
$sql='  SELECT * FROM usuarios 
        WHERE username="'.$usuario.'" 
        AND pass="'.$clave.'"
     ';
$rs=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Is this correct? Is this a good example of how to use mysqli_real_escape_string?

Comment: if you're using mysqli, then you shouldn't be escaping values yourself. use placeholders and let the database do all the work for you. But otherwise, yes, you're using it "correctly", inasmuch using an incorrect/obsolete coding method can be considered "correct"

Comment: Prepared/parameterized queries are the way to go.  I wouldn't call this correct.

Comment: FYI, having passwords in the database without encryption is about as bad as not escaping input. And I don't mean md5 -- use a proper one-way encryption with salt.

Comment: Please give me example before `mysqli_real_escape_string` and after the string which gets generated. As it casuse confusion and no example is given.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Is this correct?

Yes. This isolated handpicked example is safe. **It doesn't mean**, however, that mysqli_real_escape_string should be viewed as a function that's purpose is to prevent SQL injections. Because in this example it protects you **only by accident**. As silly example as one provided below can demonstrate that:

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["id"]);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = $id';
$rs = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
```

Here, almost any SQL can be added to $_POST["id"] and wreck havok in your database.

> Is this a good example of how to use mysqli_real_escape_string?

## Not at all

This function should be abandoned in favor of using **parameters** in the query. This function will fail you with any query part other than a string literal. And can be even simply overlooked.

A **placeholder**, also called a parameter, have to be used instead, to represent the data in your query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username=?';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['usuario']);
$stmt->execute();
$rs = $stmt->get_result();
```

See other examples in my article on the [correct use of mysqli](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli)

*If ever used*, this function MUST be encapsulated into another function that does both escaping AND adding quotes, just like `PDO::quote()` does. Only this way it will be safe.

Comment: Please give me example before `mysqli_real_escape_string` and after the string which gets generated. As it casuse confusion and no example is given.

Comment: could  be `mysqli_real_escape_string` used together with a stored procedure? for example: `$code = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, filter_var($_POST["code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)); mysqli_query($link, "CALL sp_updatetable('$code')")` ? - please note: `code` isn't user input.

Comment: @deblocker anything said in the answer is applicable to stored procedures. Simply because calling a procedure is just an SQL query, like any other.

Answer (score 5):

The use of mysqli() functions should only be reserved for framework developers and others who are aware of all the safety issues it can bring. For everyone else, there's [PDO](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059). It's just as easy to use as mysqli(), and far safer.

Comment: "*It's just as easy to use as mysqli(), and **far safer.***" - [citation needed]

Comment: Well, the link I posted explains why PDO is safer than mysqli() and string concatenation. If you are still not convinced, there's [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection) discussion that's from 2008, and still relevant today. Immunity against a large part of SQL attacks definitely qualifies as "far safer" in my opinion.

Comment: I have read that article before and I don't see where it explains "PDO is *safer*".

Comment: The article does not have to use the words "safer" to imply it. "Even if you're only going to use it once, using prepared statements will help protect you from SQL injection attacks."

Comment: In case you didn't know that before, PDO doesn't hold the monopoly for the prepared statements.

Comment: I do like the syntax of PDO's prepared statements better, but mysqli can utilize prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php.  Also, for the record, if you use PDO::query and PDO::execute, it can be just as unsafe as the old-school mysql_query if you don't sanitize (`quote()`) your input. So, there is no "immunity against" sql attacks.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you will use it save now.

The nice thing about using mysqli is that it is Object oriented.
So you can use it like this:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database");

$usuario = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["usuario"]);
$clave = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["clave"]);

$sql='  SELECT * FROM usuarios 
        WHERE username="'.$usuario.'" 
        AND pass="'.$clave.'"
     ';

$mysqli->query($sql);

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Or you can use PDO.

Comment: Please dont use non prepared statements. Seriously, just dont/. 

Theres a couple of decades worth of exploits that abuse unicode and other edge cases to get around mysql_real_escape and real_escape . Just put it in a prepared statement and let the driver handle it.