# Confused about PHP syntax for inserting variables in SQL query

Tags: php, sql, syntax

```
$firstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['newFirstName']);
$lastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['newLastName']);
$emailAddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['newEmailAddress']);

$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO admins (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ('$firstName','$lastName','$emailAddress')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE firstname ='".$firstName."' lastname='".$lastName."' email='".$emailAddress."'";
```

My issue is on the last line. AFAIK you have to use double quotes for PHP to actually insert your variable into the string, but no matter what quotes I use I get errors. What's the proper syntax for inserting the variables?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Also note that even though you escaped your input, you still are vulnerable to sql injection. Always prepare statements! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304930/is-mysqli-real-escape-string-safe

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing commas from your SQL query in between the parameters you are updating.

Additionally for your update statement, you need to specify the table and SET:

```
"Update admins
Set firstname = '". $firstname . "' , lastname = '" . $lastname . "' " etc.
```

Comment: Great.  Where exactly would I put that?

Comment: After 'on duplicate key' in place of your current update statement.

Answer (score 1):

You should separate the columns you're updating with a comma. e.g:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE firstname ='".$firstName."', lastname='".$lastName."', 
email='".$emailAddress."'";
```