# string with CRLF send via XMLHttpRequest did not preserve new line in string

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I red some questions here about preserving new line character (\n\r) when saving <textarea> content into mysql table. They said mysqli_real_escape_string() will escape and preserve the new line characters, but after trying it, I found out that the new line characters in my string are all gone in the saved string.

Details: I have 2 rows saved in a tiny text column in my table:
[image]

Row 25 is what I have saved using mysqli_real_escape_string(), and Row 24 is the same string, but I manually added the new line characters in phpMyAdmin by editing the string directly.

Note that row 25 is displayed as single string, which means the new lines are not preserved.

Copying the string and paste into Notepad++ to show the invisible control characters result in this:
[image]

Row 1 is the one saved with mysqli_real_escape_string(), while the apostrophe was escaped, the \n\r characters are not there. Note the LF/CR are totally missing in line 1, the ones in the screen is because I added newlines to separate the 2 strings.

Rows 3, 4 and 5 are how it is, for data row 24, where I manually added the new line characters in: the CR/LF characters are in the string retrieved from database.

Question: How do I preserve the CR/LF (or \n\r) characters when saving to mysql tables (given that mysqli_real_escape_string() didn't work here)? What have I been missing/misunderstood?

Thanks in advance.

P/S: please take note that I parse the text in my JS code using string.split('\n'), so I'm not using <br>(nl2br) or <pre>, they mess up the way I want my data to be shown on the webpage, anyway.

P/S2: Both my webpage and my mysql database are using UTF-8 char set.

Edit: Upon request, here are the codes.

HTML:

```
<input type="date" name="seldate" id="seldate" oninput="" class="form-control my-2">
<textarea id="newevent" name="newevent" class="form-control my-2"></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
const edate = document.getElementById("seldate");  
const event = document.getElementById("newevent");


// XMLHttpRequest
request.open("GET", "php/addevent.php?date=" + edate.value + "&event=" + event.value, true);
```

The PHP code to save the data:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")
{    
    $usid  = $_SESSION["usid"];
    $date  = $_GET["date"];
    $event = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET["event"]);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO events (ownr, date, type, detl) VALUES(?, ?, 'PUB', ?)";

    try
    {
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);
        if($stmt)
        {
            if(mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $usid, $date, $event))
            {
                if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
                {
                    $numrows = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
                    if($numrows > 0)
                    {
                        $response = array("result"=>"PASS");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $response = array("result"=>"FAIL", "reason"=>"Zero result");
                    }
                    echo json_encode($response);                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I omitted the else's and catch here since they don't affect the results.

As for the reading part, just a simple prepared mysql query.

Comment: If the `'` ended up as `\'` in your database then you didn't use the function properly. Show us the code that creates the query and any preprocessing you do on the string.

Comment: As you are using prepared statements, why is the real escape string function being used at all? Also, see [this info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22305173/7644018)

Comment: @PaulT. well I am desperate and will try anything, other similar questions has people says mysqli_real_escape_string() will preserve the CRLF so I tried it, it is not working so I asked question here.

Comment: After tracing the data being send, I suspect that the CRLF are lost when XMLHttpRequest is sending the value as URL. The data received at my php page ($_GET) is without CRLF. Now I need a solution on how to preserve the CRLF when sending data as GET (or even POST) parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy to announce that I found the source of problem: the URL encoding at XMLHttpRequest. It strips the `CRLF` from the string.

The solution is to use `encodeURI()` on the text from the `<textarea>` and the `CRLF` is preserved and send to my PHP page correctly. The `mysqli_...()` is not needed after all.